# ObjectListView get object with contextmenu

Tags: c#, events, contextmenu, objectlistview

Hy!

I would like to create an ObjectListView, where you can delete items with a ContextMenu.

So basicly I used to delete it by getting OLV.SelectedIndex, and then deleting from the list OLV is based on, and re-setting the OLV objects. 
Then I realized, if I sort the OLV, then delete an item, it deletes another item, since the selected item index does not equals the index in the list.

With OLV CellRightClick event I can get the object behind the clicked item (e.Model),but I dont know how to pass it to the ContextMenu click event handler.

Subjects is a List.

```
private void subjectListView_CellRightClick(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellRightClickEventArgs e)
{
if (subjectsListView.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.MenuItems.Add("Delete", new EventHandler(DeleteItem));
subjectsListView.ContextMenu = cm;
}
}

void DeleteItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//get the Subject object, which was clicked on
Subjects.RemoveAt(subjectsListView.SelectedIndex);
subjectsListView.SetObjects(Subjects);
}
```

So basically I want to get the object (not the index) when the ContextMenus "Delete" item is clicked.
Also, I feel like there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just assign an appropriate ContextMenuStrip from the designer to the ObjectListView.ContextMenuStrip property and then handle the click of the corresponding "Delete" click like this:

```
    private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (objectListView1.SelectedObject != null) {
            objectListView1.RemoveObject(objectListView1.SelectedObject);
        }
    }
```

Or is there a requirement I am missing from your question?

Comment: Well 'RemoveObject' only removes from the OLV, and my problem is that its not syncronized with the list OLV reads data from. 

Also when user sorts the OLV, the list it uses does not sort, so its in another sequence, so getting by OLV selected index gets another object.

Comment: Can't you just remove the SelectedObject from the source list as well? The object reference should be the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right, didnt have time to think it over yesterday, also didnt know about this method, and .SelectedObject property, thank you

Comment: The fact that the SelectedObject holds the item where the click occurred was something I didn't get from the documentation. Thanks.